# Why does assembleDebug takes much longer then project build and how to optimize it?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've been dealing with gradle build time in Android Studio recently. I've managed to decrease the build time from about 3 mins to 10 seconds by removing some dependencies, but here's the thing:

When I rebuild project it takes about 10 seconds:

```
15:13:43 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
15:13:54 Gradle build finished in 11s 596ms
```

However when I launch the app, it takes a lot longer, about a minute:

```
15:15:09 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
15:15:58 Gradle build finished in 49s 676ms
```

What is the cause of such big difference? Is this still because of the large amount of gradle dependencies or something else? Can I reduce the build time somehow?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### **Why:**

Recently I enabled [multidex](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html) in my app because I had over 65k methods. **Dexing** is what was taking a lot of time to complete.

### **How to speed up build:**

Go to **Settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>) -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Compiler**

Enabling compiling modules in parallel and adding `--offline` in compiler has decreased my execution time to about 15 seconds.

[image]

Comment: This was amazing, my execution time decreased about 7 minutes. Thank you very much.

Comment: How to do that in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Is there a command-line option for the first one, i.e for a parallel build?

Comment: This worked great for a few minutes, then it kept complaining this gradle version is not available for caching for offline use. I had to finally leave it alone